# Где нужно хранить файлы при использовании докера

Tags: сервер, docker, администрирование, docker-compose

Используется докер для проекта, бд и файловая система прокидывается в докер контейнеры, но сейчас возникли проблемы с производительностью и даже с ребилдом.

По размерам 8ГБ бд и 50ГБ данных которые используется приложением.
Общий объем диска сервера 160 ГБ из которых около 100 ГБ свободных.

При ребилде вылетает ошибка о нехватке памяти.
Приаттачу конфиги docker-compose.yml для первых двух контейнеров, остальные по такому же принципу настроены.

```
    version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    links:
      - php-fpm
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    - ./docker/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    restart: always

  php-fpm:
    container_name: fpm
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    - ./docker/php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    environment:
      DB_PORT: "3306"
      DB_HOST: "mysql"
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "es:9200"
      REDIS_PORT: "6379"
      REDIS_HOST: "redis"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=aggregator"
    restart: always
```

соответственно опцией

```
build:
  context: ./
```

Прокидывается все что в корне проекта и сторедж в том числе.
Подскажите правильно ли я сделал, если нет то что нужно поменять?

Comment: Выхлоп `df -h` или `di -h` добавь в вопрос.

Comment: Стоит ошибку выложить. Не очень понятно кто именно ругается на нехватку памяти. 
Ну например у вас в Dockerfile php-fpm происходит что то, и на нехватку ругается  php интерпретатор.

Comment: Ну и если коротко, в продакшене хранить данные нужно в именованных volumes, не биндить. 
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/